# -XX:MaxPermSize with or without -XX:PermSize

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-hotspot, permgen

We've run into a **Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space** error and looking at the tomcat JVM params, other than the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` params we also specify `-XX:MaxPermSize=128m`. After a bit of profiling I can see occasionally garbage collection happening on the PermGen space saving it from running full.

My question is: other than increasing the `-XX:MaxPermSize` what would be the difference if I specify as well `-XX:PermSize`? I know the total memory then would be **Xmx+maxPermSize** but is there any other reason why `-XX:PermSize` should **not** be there when `-XX:MaxPermSize` is specified?

Please do share if you have real-world experience dealing with these JVM parameters.

ps. The JVM is HotSpot 64bit Server VM build 16.2-b04

Comment: you need to care about the max only, waste of the energy and the entropy b/c of this very question will never come close to saving of "perfectly" tuning the jvm. maxPerGen is important and specify any arbitrary high value, the jvm wont commit before it actually needs.

Answer (score 49):

`-XX:PermSize` specifies the initial size that will be allocated during startup of the JVM. If necessary, the JVM will allocate up to `-XX:MaxPermSize`.

Comment: true. It also makes the difference that the total memory appears as Xmx+maxPermSize which is very important. That's why I am asking whether there is anything else going on.

Comment: The total memory consists of more than mx and maxperm. Especially you get some memory (stack) for each thread. If you have thousands (which is not a good thing) this can be up to 50% of the overall size. There might also be excessive native heap when you have some JNI implementations (for example oder SAP JCO drivers). And some compoennts use the off-heap direct mapped memory in addition.

Answer (score 26):

By playing with parameters as `-XX:PermSize` and `-Xms` you can tune the performance of - for example - the startup of your application. I haven't looked at it recently, but a few years back the default value of `-Xms` was something like 32MB (I think), if your application required a lot more than that it would trigger a number of cycles of fill memory - full garbage collect - increase memory etc until it had loaded everything it needed. This cycle can be detrimental for startup performance, so immediately assigning the number required could improve startup.

A similar cycle is applied to the permanent generation. So tuning these parameters can improve startup (amongst others).

**WARNING** The JVM has a lot of optimization and intelligence when it comes to allocating memory, dividing eden space and older generations etc, so don't do things like making `-Xms` equal to `-Xmx` or `-XX:PermSize` equal to `-XX:MaxPermSize` as it will remove some of the optimizations the JVM can apply to its allocation strategies and therefor reduce your application performance instead of improving it.

As always: make non-trivial measurements to prove your changes actually improve performance overall (for example improving startup time *could* be disastrous for performance during use of the application)

Comment: Thanks. I'm astound to see how diametrically opposite the views are on this (look at @mijer response) even in various other places. I understand this since we don't really know what this flag is doing and how it is interacting with the other one unless we study the c code of the JVM. That's why I was looking for hands-on real-life experiences.

Comment: The "don't do things like making `-Xms` equal to `-Xmx`" comment is not shared by all users. Tomcat specifically recommends setting them to the same value. http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2011/11/22/performance-tuning-jvm-running-tomcat

Comment: @JohnHinnegan Setting it to the same value does have its advantages (such as less garbage collection during startup), but as I said in my answer it will prevent the JVM from making some optimizations. And in that event you will either have to live with it or do those optimizations yourself with the commandline options of the JVM.

Comment: +1 with Mark, don't do that upfront. Re-posting: to try to explain a bit why that "set -Xms=Xmx" value is so much spread, I think this is due to the fact that many years ago the JVM was much less capable of autoadaptation. Nowadays, I'd recommend to do that as a last resort after a serious phase of perf testing. Indeed, the JVM has gotten very good in autoadaptation, and JVM-world known expert for example Kirk Pepperdine tell that setting those values upfront would be like asking a musician to play with one hand bound in your back (heard in a training).

Comment: It's probably a good advice to not apply Xms=Xmx as a recipe. But in some cases it can be the good choice, it depends what you want to optimize. Do you want to optimize the application throughput or its memory fingerprint?

Comment: Can you be more specific about from which version or date of JVM is much more autoadaptive with Xms<Xmx setting?

Comment: @Onur iirc, that started with Java 5, and it has improved which each version

Answer (score 8):

If you're doing some performance tuning it's often recommended to set both `-XX:PermSize` and `-XX:MaxPermSize` to the same value to increase `JVM` efficiency.

Here is some information:

1. [Support for large page heap on x86 and amd64 platforms](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html#2.1.4)
2. [Java Support for Large Memory Pages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/largememory-jsp-137182.html?ssSourceSiteId=ocomen)
3. [Setting the Permanent Generation Size](http://wikis.oracle.com/display/CommSuite/Convergence+Performance+Tuning#ConvergencePerformanceTuning-SettingthePermanentGenerationSize)

You can also specify `-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled` to enable class unloading
option if you are using `CMS` `GC`. It may help to decrease the probability of `Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space`

Comment: Thanks. I'm astound to see how diametrically opposite the views are on this (look at @Mark Rotteveel response) even in various other places. I understand this since we don't really know what this flag is doing and how it is interacting with the other one unless we study the c code of the JVM. That's why I was looking for hands-on real-life experiences.

Comment: See also [GC Tuning Java 6](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html) _Setting -Xms and -Xmx to the same value increases predictability by removing the most important sizing decision from the virtual machine. On the other hand, the virtual machine can't compensate if you make a poor choice._

Comment: To try to explain a bit why that "set -Xms=Xmx" value is so much spread, I think this is due to the fact that many years ago the JVM was much less capable of autoadaptation. Nowadays, I'd recommend to do that as a *last resort* after a serious phase of perf testing. Indeed, the JVM has gotten very good in autoadaptation, and JVM-world known expert for example Kirk Pepperdine tell that setting those values upfront would be like asking a musician to play with one hand bound in your back (heard in a training).

Comment: I work on low-latency applications for several years. There is no simple performance recipes, it depends what we want to optimize (cost, latency, ...) I frequently applied Xms=Xmx to improve performance. This tuning is relevant when it doesn't make sense to let the JVM does complex calculations to adapt its consumption because we book underlying resources. Obviously this needs a serious phase of thinking/testing, not only to put the good tuning on the Java command line, but also to buy the good underlying hardware.

Comment: 3rd link's broken  FYI