# JAVA PermGem memory

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, gate

Please help me to find it out how to increase the JAVA heap space, I am running GATE based application where I need to run large collection of datasets, and it's really eating the memory. My computer configuration is RAM 32GB window 7. Whenever I run the dataset it when it reaches the memory size(1.5g) stops and says no memory (PermGem space available) and it kills the program. Is it true that maximum memory we can allocate to JAVA as -Xmx as 1.5g by default, we tried to increase the memory but no success still it crashes the program at 1.5g. How we could increase the memory size upto 8GB or more? Because I read that we could allocate 1/3 of physical memory to JAVA to run the program is it true? Please help me?
Thanks

Comment: "*How we could increase the memory size upto 8GB or more?*" with a 64  bit OS and a 64 bit JVM...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Increase heap size in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java)

Comment: I recommend using Google query for searching StackOverflow, in this case it would be something like: `java increase heap site:stackoverflow.com`. I found massive amount of other similar questions.

Comment: If windows 7 is a PROFESSIONAL / ENTERPRISE / ULTIMATE 64bit version  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7) there is no problem. Install a 64bit JVM and follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8356416/xxmaxpermsize-with-or-without-xxpermsize

Comment: PermGen is not the same thing as heap space.  If you're exhausting the PermGen space, then you must be loading lots of libraries, or you have too many static variables.

Answer (score 1):

The PermGen space is specific to Oracle JVM. You can increase it with the a VM arg like [-XX:MaxPermSize=128M](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_permgen_size_available_to_Eclipse?).